# Flex/AS3 ADG: Trouble with edit-cell behaviour

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm developing different applications using ActionScript3 and the Adobe Flex3.6 framework. In most of the projects I make use of the AdvancedDataGrid component which gives me a recurring problem when enabling editing of cells only for specific columns. This is achieved by catching the itemEditBegin event and checking from which position (row,column) the event was fired. If the current cell should not be edited event.preventDefault() is called.

But in some cases it happens that the cell (0,0) can be edited even if this should not be possible from the restrictions from the event handler method for catching the itemEditBegin event.

What I can observe is that when this problem happens the itemEditBegin event is not fired. So could it be a problem or a bug in the Flex3 Framework?

I didn't check if this problem occurs also when using Flex4.!

Please check the attached screenshot to get a better understanding of the problem.

[image]

Comment: I've not encountered this bug, though I've used the ADG extensively I rarely used the inline editing feature (generally has just been for display purposes) so I haven't encountered this issue but what I would do in this scenario is search the Flex source for the event in question, determine where it is actually dispatched from, grep or windows grep for the event name then the constant that matches it and look for any dispatchEvent calls.  Then it's just a matter of figuring out why it could possibly not hit that line.

Comment: Perhaps you don't get the itemEditBegin event in cell 0,0 because it's the first cell -- and I imagine initially all of your columns are editable? Does the problem happen when the grid is first rendered? Is it possible to turn this problem on it's ear, and dynamically enable/disable editing of the grid columns (rather than having them all be editable)?

Comment: Would help if you posted some code that replicates the issue.